# Passing byte to a method that takes UInt8 (Java)

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I am new to Java and I am a little confused about converting data types. I basically have a byte that was retrieved from a byte array, and I am trying to pass it to a method that takes an argument of type UInt8. But I am not sure how to do the conversion from byte to UInt8.

Below is some (pseudo) code that describes the problem:

Let's say we have a byte array:

```java
byte[] byteArray = ...
```

And have a method like:

```java
returnClass method(UInt8 argument) {
    ...
}
```

I want to call the method and pass it, for instance, the 0th element in the byte array:

```java
method( byteArray[0] );
```

But this gives me an error saying that the argument is incompatible.

I tried casting it to UInt8, like:

```java
method( (UInt8) byteArray[0] );
```

But this gives me an error saying cannot cast from UInt8 to byte.

Please let me know how I can go about this problem.

Comment: UInt8 is not a built-in Java type.  We have no idea how to interact with it, because we have no idea where it comes from.

Comment: What is `UInt8`? Which library are you using where this argument is needed?

Comment: @LouisWasserman, i just found out UInt8 is from an internal library. However, I can't view the source code. Also, I found another method in our library `parseUInt8(String arg0)` that I am thinking I could use. Is there a way to convert the byte to String?

Comment: @rocketfinger We can't answer that question, or your original question, without seeing `UInt8` or its documentation.  If that's internal, then there's very little we can do to answer your questions.

Comment: When you say internal library, do you mean internal to your company, or internal to the java implementation? Java disassemblers are excellent, so viewing the source(minus some local variable names), should be easy if you have an ide(like intellij) that can disassemble for you. To go from byte to string you can do `Byte(b).toString()`.

Comment: You don’t need the source of UInt8, just the public method signatures.  Hopefully someone has generated javadoc of the library.

Comment: @rocketfinger Which library are you using which defines the `UInt8` class? Where is the link to the documentation of that library?